# Como aparecer o erro apenas do formulário validado no Flask em Python?

Tags: python, formulário, validação, flask

Com dois formulários simples em flask na mesma página, botei a validação de email pra ser um exemplo: [Fórmularios de emails](https://Problema-formulario.niltonklebert.repl.co)
 Eu coloquei para aparecer os erros de validação do formulário, o problema é que quando tento validar um formulário aparece o erro de validação nos dois formulários assim (e não apenas no que foi validado): [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código do app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Email

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'C2HWGVoMGfNTBsrYQg8EcMrdTimkZfAb'

#Formularios
class Form1(FlaskForm):
  email = StringField('Email:', validators=[Email()])
  botao1 = SubmitField('Enviar1')

class Form2(FlaskForm):
  email = StringField('Email:', validators=[Email()])
  botao2 = SubmitField('Enviar2')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
  form1 = Form1()
  form2 = Form2()
  if form1.validate_on_submit() and 'botao1' in request.form:
    return 'Enviou 1'
  if form2.validate_on_submit() and 'botao2' in request.form:
    return 'Enviou 2'
  return render_template('index.html', form1=form1, form2=form2)

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)
```

E o index.html na pasta templates, o código é:

```
<div>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form1.csrf_token }}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form1.email.label() }}
        {{ form1.email() }}
        {% if form1.email.errors %}
          {% for erro in form1.email.errors %}
            {{ erro }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
    {{ form1.botao1() }}
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form2.csrf_token }}
    <fieldset method="POST" action="">
        {{ form2.email.label() }}
        {{ form2.email() }}
        {% if form2.email.errors %}
          {% for erro in form2.email.errors %}
            {{ erro }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </fieldset>
    {{ form2.botao2() }}
  </form>
</div>
```

Os códigos também podem ser vistos [Aqui](https://replit.com/@niltonklebert/Problema-formulario#main.py)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução para o problema é adicionar um condicional para aparecer o erro, que reconhece quando o botão do respectivo formulário for apertado, fica assim:

```
{% if form1.email.errors and 'botao1' in request.form %}
  {% for erro in form1.email.errors %}
    {{ erro }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Para melhorar ainda mais, basta deixar o nome dos parâmetros diferentes entre os formulários, assim:

```
class Form1(FlaskForm):
  email1 = StringField('Email:', validators=[Email()])
  botao1 = SubmitField('Enviar1')

class Form2(FlaskForm):
  email2 = StringField('Email:', validators=[Email()])
  botao2 = SubmitField('Enviar2')
```

Tem assim o resultado esperado:
[image: um de dois formulários com erro]

O resultado pode ser testado [aqui](https://problema-formulario-solucao.niltonklebert.repl.co/), e o código completo [aqui](https://replit.com/@niltonklebert/Problema-formulario-Solucao#main.py).